# Exchange from FlowRouter to IronRouter

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, flow-router

I have a little problem. Need help to exchange code fragment from FlowRouter to IronRouter.
Fragment to exchange:

```
FlowRouter.getParam("appId");
```

I need this to take a id from this [url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb5L6.png) make my project great again.

Routes.js
`this.route('usersUpdate', {
  path: '/users/update/:uId',
  template: 'usersUpdate'
});`

In final i`ll make something like this, but in IronRouter

```
Template.usersUpdate.helpers({
 getUserId () {
  return FlowRouter.getParam('uID');
 }
})
```

How to do this better and correct? (Sorry for bad English^^)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know how to retrieve the uId parameter used in the url. If so, you retrieve like this in IronRouter:

```
Template.usersUpdate.helpers({
   getUserId: () => Router.current().params.uID
})
```